# CAP#1 error with Realm and Parceler

Tags: java, realm

I'm trying to use this class https://gist.github.com/patloew/bc32a2a1a3c0097e9c7020192fb2c78f together with Realm database, but I can't get it to work.

I have a class that looks like

```
@Parcel(implementations = { MonthRealmProxy.class },
        value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN,
        analyze = { Month.class })
public class Month extends RealmObject {
RealmList<Day> days;

public RealmList<Day> getDays() {
        return sessions;
    }
@ParcelPropertyConverter(RealmListParcelConverter.class)
    public void setDays(RealmList<Day> days) {
        this.days= days;
    }
}
```

and Day looks like

```
@Parcel(implementations = { DayRealmProxy.class },
        value = Parcel.Serialization.BEAN,
        analyze = { Day.class })
public class Day extends RealmObject {

    public int hours;

}
```

but when compiling I get this error and I don't know what's wrong:

```
Error:(79, 100) error: incompatible types: RealmList<CAP#1> cannot be converted to RealmList<Day>
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
CAP#1 extends RealmObject from capture of ? extends RealmObject
```

I'm thankful for any help, since I've spent hours on this without understanding it.

Comment: Did you made an adapter for a RealmList? If you didn't make an adapter, see the following code: https://gist.github.com/cmelchior/72c35fcb55cec33a71e1

Comment: Adapter? So the class is not used to replace https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cmelchior/72c35fcb55cec33a71e1/raw/a9297b5ee8878c3046d3d728b1087975704e9f3d/BarListParcelConverter.java and https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cmelchior/72c35fcb55cec33a71e1/raw/a9297b5ee8878c3046d3d728b1087975704e9f3d/RealmListParcelConverter.java with one generic single class?

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood your code. patloew's code and your models seems OK. Can you share your code to help@realm.io?

Comment: Thanks, I've send the project now.

Answer (score 0):

The guide at https://gist.github.com/patloew/bc32a2a1a3c0097e9c7020192fb2c78f produces the compile messages mentioned in your question. It seems to be safer to create separate converters, and follow the guide at https://gist.github.com/cmelchior/72c35fcb55cec33a71e1.

Comment: Seperated converters was what I tried to avoid, but I guess that it's not possible any more then..